# "The book is still read after three hundred years." or "The book is still being read after three hundred years."

Tags: difference, tense

> The book is still read after three hundred years.

Or

> The book is still being read after three hundred years.

Comment: They are both grammatically correct, but "is still being read" sounds like someone has been continuously reading it for three hundred years!  Either it is a very long book, or he is a very slow reader!

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295944/can-we-use-adjectives-and-leave-out-the-being

Comment: I would  use the second one. That is what one would generally encounter and it does not mean continuously.

Comment: "still read" suggests reading the whole thing; "being read" suggests parts of it (or incompletely). This is the same as other past simple/progressive differences e.g.  "I read" vs "I was reading".

Comment: @All Do note that 'read' is not an ordinary predicate adjective in these sentences - it is part of the *present passive indicative* tense regardless of whether you use the simple ("is read") or progressive ("is being read") aspect

Answer (score -1):

Both are fine. But the second one adds an air of progressiveness.